# Does BaseAdapter change colors of widgets?

Tags: java, android, widget, baseadapter

Widgets are dim, but they haven't alpha and they are enable.

[ListView with BaseAdapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgc62.png)

```
@Override 
public View getView(final int index, View p2, ViewGroup p3){
    View v = p2;
    if (v == null) v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layer, null);
    //There is a code with setting listeners to widgets
    return v;
}
```

What is the problem?